# add properties to output object and convert to array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, ecmascript-6

This is my request body which I am sending to back end,

```
{
    "appId":'10001',
    "upstream":[
        {
          "name":"john",
          "content":"APPLICATION 1"
        },
        {
          "name":"peter",
          "content":"APPLICATION 2"
        },
    ],
    "downstream":[
        {
          "name":"max",
          "content":"APPLICATION 3"
        },
{
          "name":"justin",
          "content":"APPLICATION 4"
        },

    ],
}
```

I want to convert the same like below,

```
[
 {
    "appId":'10001',
    "name":"john",
    "content":"APPLICATION 1",
    "type":"upstream"
 },
 {
    "appId":'10001',
    "name":"peter",
    "content":"APPLICATION 2",
    "type":"upstream"
 },
 {
    "appId":'10001',
    "name":"max",
    "content":"APPLICATION 3",
    "type":"downstream"
 },
 {
    "appId":'10001',
    "name":"justin",
    "content":"APPLICATION 4",
    "type":"downstream"
 },
]
```

This needs to be done using Javascript (ES6).with the help of map function or any other ES6 utilities.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An improved solution using modern syntax can be:

```
const input = {
  appId: "10001",
  upstream: [
    {
      name: "john",
      content: "APPLICATION 1",
    },
    {
      name: "peter",
      content: "APPLICATION 2",
    },
  ],
  downstream: [
    {
      name: "max",
      content: "APPLICATION 3",
    },
    {
      name: "justin",
      content: "APPLICATION 4",
    },
  ],
};

const upstreams = input.upstream.map((v) => ({ appId: input.appId, ...v, type: "upstream" }));
const downstreams = input.downstream.map((v) => ({ appId: input.appId, ...v, type: "downstream" }));
const results = [...upstreams, ...downstreams];

console.log(results);
```

Here, we're creating a new array `upstreams`, which will be filled with the results of calling the first array of objects in `input` and adding to it additional key-value pairs (`appId` and the appropriate `type`). Same for the `downstreams` array.

We used the spread operator `...` to quickly copy all of an existing array/object into another array/object.

And the keyword `const` instead of `var` since we're not going to mutate all used symbols.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to convert it -

```
var input = {
    "appId": '10001',
    "upstream": [
        {
            "name": "john",
            "content": "APPLICATION 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "peter",
            "content": "APPLICATION 2"
        },
    ],
    "downstream": [
        {
            "name": "max",
            "content": "APPLICATION 3"
        },
        {
            "name": "justin",
            "content": "APPLICATION 4"
        },
    ],
};

var upstreams = input.upstream.map(v => { return {appId: input.appId, name: v.name, content: v.content, type: 'upstream'} });
var downstreams = input.downstream.map(v => { return {appId: input.appId, name: v.name, content: v.content, type: 'downstream'} });
var result = upstreams.concat(downstreams);
console.log(result);
```